# Spawned tasks are stopping before finishing (and I dont think it's due to failure). Is my code wrong?

Tags: elixir

I am uploading images, and then creating different file sizes for each image.

I have a GenServer that handles the initial file being uploaded. It keeps the state of the incrementing file ID. (uploads/1/original.png, uploads/2/original.png, etc.).

Once that original file is created, I handle the other sizes with processes. Like this:

```
def handle_call({:upload, temp_filepath, filename}, _from, state) do
    ...code...
    # Here the upload tempfile is copied to file
    File.cp(temp_filepath, new_filepath)
    # spawn task to create other versions
    spawn(fn ->
       AppName.ImageUploadResizer.create_files(new_filepath)
    end)
    # The upload GenServer just returns the original file upload url
    {:reply, asset_path(new_filepath), state + 1}
end
```

Here is the code to create the different versions

```
defmodule AppName.ImageUploadResizer do
  import Mogrify

  @types [{"thumbnail", 50}, {"medium", 150}, {"large", 500}]

  def create_files(filepath, types \\ @types) do
    for type <- types do
      new_filepath = String.replace(filepath, "original", elem(type, 0))
      new_size = elem(type, 1)
      spawn(fn ->
        open(filepath)
        |> copy
        |> resize(new_size)
        |> save(new_filepath)
        IO.puts "Created a new image size"
      end)
    end
  end
end
```

With both spawns (in the GenServer and the 3 in ImageUploadResizer), none of the resizes are created. If I spawn in the Resizer, but not the Server. One (thumbnail), is created. If  I remove all spawns, all are created.

Any idea why this is not working as intended? Should I not be using spawn here? What is a better design?

EDIT:

If I add two print statements, like this:

```
def create_files(filepath, types \\ @types) do
    for {type, size} <- types do
      spawn(fn ->
        IO.puts "\n BEFORE \n"
        open(filepath)
        |> copy
        |> resize(size)
        |> save(String.replace(filepath, "original", type))
        IO.puts "\n AFTER \n"
      end)
    end
  end
```

And I run it a few times. I always get 3 "BEFORE", and I get 1, sometimes 2 "AFTER". Without the spawn, I get 3 "BEFORE", and 3 "AFTER".

After more investigation (printing after each step), it seems to be dying on the `resize` call which I assume is the longest running call here.

But I still dont think it's an ImageMagick issue. Is it possible that the process is being terminated or killed before

It seems to me like the process is dying or being killed before it can finish.

Comment: So if you spawn in both places, `"Created a new image size"` is never printed?

Comment: The code looks correct. The only thing I would change is using pattern match instead of elem like this: `for {type, size} <- types`. The design problem is that those processes are unsupervised. You should create `:simple_one_for_one` supervisor. This also adds logging, so it may help pinpoint the issue. Can you distill working example on GitHub, so we can download and play with it? Maybe ImageMagick can't process one file by many processes? Hard to tell.

Comment: @Dogbert Correct. It is never printed.

Comment: @PeterR what if you move it to before `open(filepath)`?

Comment: @Dogbert Please see my edit.

Comment: @tkowal I have uploaded the basics. https://github.com/perich/UploaderEX

run ```mix test test/uploader_test.exs```, you'll see 3 "BEFORE" statements. and you'll see only the original file in ```priv/static/images/NUM/```, if you remove the ```spawn``` in ```lib/post_upload_resizer.ex```, then you'll see that it works fine. Is there a reason for this not working? Did I design this wrong? How can I build a simple supervisor? Is it better to do it without spawn?

Comment: @PeterR If I add `:timer.sleep(5000)` before the end of the test body, I get all "AFTER" messages. It seems like your tests are ending before the resize is finished.

Comment: @Dogbert But shouldn't the processes still run? The "AFTER" is just a canary, the real test is whether the new files are created, which they dont seem to be.

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies with tests not waiting until you are done with the task. Here is how it goes:

- start the gen_server with `start_link`
- process the message in handle_call
- spawn first resizer
- spawn second resizer
- spawn third resizer
- return from the gen_server call
- finish the test
- the virtual machine exits when the test case process is finished and all processes are gone (even if they haven't finished themselves)

The resizer processes are killed just after they print `BEFORE` message, but before doing any actual work.

Unit tests are great for testing logic, but less so for testing processes interaction. I would extract the:

```
open(filepath)
  |> copy
  |> resize(size)
  |> save(String.replace(filepath, "original", type))
```

part to its own function and test it separately from managing processes.

Another option is to add code that sends responses. Now you are returning new asset_path even before you know that the files were actually created. It might be good idea to wait for responses from file resizing like this:

```
tasks = for {type, size} <- types do
  Task.async(fn -> resize(type, size, filepath) end)
end
for task <- tasks do
  Task.await(task)
end
```

This code still processes three image resizing operations in parallel, but returns only when all are finished, so testing is easier. This is also good if you need to add back pressure later on.

If your code doesn't send any responses back you can only call it asynchronously. If it sends responses, you might call it synchronously, but you can also wrap it in `Task.async` and make it asynchronous this way. It is a good idea to keep things synchronous when you want to test them.

One last tip for beginners is: never use raw `spawn` or `spawn_link`. Those are low level abstractions like assembler code for Erlang processes. Try to use Applications, Supervisors, GenServers, Tasks and Agents.